# Stuck on SSRS insert stored proc

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, ssrs-2008

I have created a update tool in SSRS that writes holiday details to the specified data base. This has been created by using an insert stored procedure as the dataset in the report. Everything works fine as long as i only want to specify single dates. Ideally though i need get this to do a date range. I have the following columns that are needed:

```
HolidayDate|StaffCode|HolidayType|FTE
```

I know this would be best done in .net or something similar but that's a little outside my skill set. What i need is a multi-paramater stored proc that will create a record for each date based on selecting a date range in SSRS. Standard SSRS report would be easy, a simple `BETWEEN @DATE AND @DATE` But i can't figure out a way of putting that into my set up and i'm getting frustrated.

Hope i've not been too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of the matter here is you really need to be able to get a list of dates between start/end date.

Keeping it simple, let's say you have report parameters `@StartDate`, `@EndDate` and `@StaffCode`, with values of *01-Jan-2013*, *05-Jan-2013* and *Staff1* respectively.

Your SP will have three corresponding parameters - based on these we can build a list of days for that `StaffCode` in the SP.

Here's one way of doing it:

```
create procedure MySP
(
  @StartDate date
  , @EndDate date
  , @StaffCode varchar(10)
) as

with dates as
(
  select HolidayDate = @startDate
  union all
  select HolidayDate = dateadd(dd, 1, HolidayDate)
  from dates
  where dateadd(dd, 1, HolidayDate) <= @EndDate
)
insert into HolidayDates
select HolidayDate, StaffCode = @StaffCode
from dates;
```

So this inserts a row for each date from `@StartDate` to `@EndDate`.

This is just one example, and I used a recursive CTE to make the dates set - if you had a calendar or numbers table you could just use this instead; there are numerous examples out there.

Another approach is just build up a set based with a loop based on the date parameters:

```
create procedure MySP
(
  @StartDate date
  , @EndDate date
  , @StaffCode varchar(10)
) as

declare @Dates table (HolidayDate date)

while (@StartDate <= @EndDate)
begin

  insert into @Dates select @StartDate
  select @StartDate = dateadd(dd, 1, @StartDate)

end

insert into HolidayDates
select HolidayDate, StaffCode = @StaffCode
from @Dates;
```

You've said yourself this isn't an ideal workflow - SSRS isn't really a data entry mechanism, but there's no reason why the above shouldn't work in most cases.

Comment: Actaully thinking about it a CTE would work, the report can create the base data then the rest of the stored proc could transform the data through the CTE. Just need to figure out the CTE now! will post as a seperate questions though. Thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: No problem! If you don't feel like using a CTE you could get your list of dates with a loop, even; see above.